# bad request error 400 google api for translation python

Tags: python, google-translate

calling API and getting the error need to translate from English to France but getting this error so I have used  this code but it is not working properly

code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

__author__ = 'jcgregorio@google.com (Joe Gregorio)'

from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def main():

  service = build('translate', 'v2',
            developerKey='AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0')
  print(service.translations().list(
      source='en',
      target='fr',
     q="flower"
    ).execute())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trail.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "trail.py", line 15, in main
    q="flower"
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=flower&source=en&alt=json&target=fr&key=AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0 returned "Bad Request">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Google Cloud client library and authorize your API using service account credentials JSON and calling `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=your_service.json` instead of using the API key. You can also use default application credentials by calling `gcloud auth application-default login`.

This is demonstrated in the [Google Cloud Translate Python samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/translate/cloud-client) which should also help you get started more quickly.

Note the translate API requires billing, as [described in the translate quickstart instructions](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started), so be prepared to set that up for your project.

Comment: it is asking to enable the billing is it necessary

Comment: it is asking to enable the billing is it necessary @class

Comment: Yes. You must enable billing for some of the premium API features.